# Shapefile name specific failure with Append in ArcGIS 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, append

Can anyone tell me why the append (Desktop Management) function is not working on my 64 bit Windows 7 machine with ArcGIS 10.2.2 under the specific conditions described below?  All tests on my machine were run with Windows 7 10.2.2, except for one test specified below.  Other machines used Windows 7 and 10.1 or 10.2.2  I am unsure if the other machines were 64 or 32 bit.

The specific conditions are:

When the append function is run with two shapefiles, one named sites_p, the append tool runs successfully, but no records are appended to sites_p.  If I rename it to sites_u, sites_t, or anything else, records are appended. This error only happens when sites_p is selected in ArcMap using the dropdown selector in the Append tool.  If I add sites_p as the target dataset by selecting the filepath in ArcMap, the append function works.  It also works correctly when run from ArcCatalog

The append tool was re-run after each of the steps described below.  None of the steps resolved the issue:

The shapefiles were moved to a directory 1 level below my C drive with no success.  All the field types and widths were checked.  A blank .mxd file with only the two shapefiles was used. A new sites_p shapefile was created and tested. .net 3.5 was re-installed. I performed a clean uninstall/re-install as directed by ESRI tech support. As part of the uninstall, I also removed 64 bit background processing.  All tests were repeated after the re-install

The append tool works correctly when:

It is run on other machines with the sites_p shapefile.  The sites_p shapefile is converted to a file geodatabase named sites_p.  It is run with ArcMap 10.2.2 and the sites_p shapefile from Microsoft Windows Technical Preview on a separate partition of my hard drive.

Comment: There are lots of statements. But i don't see a question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Can anyone tell me why the append function is not working under the specific conditions listed above?  Or has anyone had similar name specific issues?

Comment: Please just reformat the original (hit edit) into a single question.

Comment: In what OS environment are you running each of these tests? (please edit the question)